# Trac Advanced Reports

Tags: mysql, trac

I have a trac report that displays how many tickets are at each stage of the workflow. Is it possible to make reports dynamic, so if a row is clicked a report for those tickets are shown.

```
SELECT stage,
count(status) as 'Number of Matches',
id as _id, 
'[..1] Tickets Here' as link
FROM ticket
```

Failing that, it would be useful to have a link to another report that shows all the tickets at that stage but links are seen as text in the report.

```
 [..1] Tickets Here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make dynamic reports using wiki pages.  Personally, I find that to be the easier approach most of the time.

For your purposes, you could have something like this:

```
== Open Tickets, By State ==
[report:4 New] ([[TicketQuery(status=new,format=count)]])\\
[report:5 Accepted] ([[TicketQuery(status=accepted,format=count)]])\\
[report:6 Code Review] ([[TicketQuery(status=codereview,format=count)]])\\
[report:7 Testing] ([[TicketQuery(status=testing,format=count)]])
```

This will result in output that looks like:

```
New (40)
Accepted (12)
Code Review (8)
Testing (17)
```

where the name of the state is a link to a detailed report listing all of the tickets in that state.  You will need to create a report for each state and fill in the correct report numbers for the `report:#` links in the example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in viewing this information per milestone then you might do well to customise your milestone page instead of creating a separate report. [This page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRoadmapCustomGroups) explaining how to create custom state groupings in the milestone progress bar will be useful to you in such case.